# Google Workspace as a service provider does not send signed requests

Tags: saml, google-workspace

I am trying to setup SSO with third party IDPs in Google Workspace admin console.

I am using SAP IAS as an IDP.

It works with the default configuration.

But if i mark the the SAML requests to IDP must be signed in SAP IAS then it fails saying "SAML requests are not signed ".

It seems Google as a service provider does not sign the requests ? is it a correct understanding or is there a way to enable signing of SAML requests in Google workspace admin console ?

Best Regards,

Saurav

Answer (score 0):

When you use Google Workspace as Service Provider with a third-party IdP requests are not signed by default and I am afraid that setting is not available in Google's side at the moment.

I assume by signing both the request and response of your SSO flow you are looking to grant extra security to this process however if you really need to use Google services and the authentication is successful without the setting I would recommend to skip this for now.

Neither in the documentation nor in the Google Admin console section for third-party IdPs SSO you would find it, the setting is simply not there:

[Google as Service Provider setup](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6349809)

[image]

I hope this information helps!